# Where did I move my file to?

Tags: 14.04, mv, tilda

Okay I just cd'ed ito my `/Downloads` directory on Ubuntu and typed

```
mv file.zip ~.
```

The command executed but where did I move my file to ? I can't find it anywhere. I thought I kept it in the /home dir, but it's not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `.` at the end is in your command, you moved it to `~.` (your renamed the file, it is still in the same directory).

If the `.` is a mistake and not in your actual command, then you moved it to /home/username (the filename stays the same).

Run the following command to move the file to your home directory:

```
mv ~/Downloads/~. ~/file.zip
```

Your home directory is `~/` not `~.`